# Disable bounty-related notifications, if there is no answer to award bounty

Tags: feature-request, bounties, notifications

My bounty failed. It was aimed to attract at least one answer, but no answer was actually given. Do I still need to see these -- a bit annoying -- reminders that my bounty is about expire within... 3 days... 1 day etc.? Can these be disabled in this situation.

I mean... what should I actually do with these reminders or what is their purpose -- what should they remind me? Neither I can't award bounty to any answer manually nor it can be awarded automatically, because... there are no answers.

Comment: Probably such messages activate you for doing more effort like making aware others that there's bounty if you're interested via chat-rooms etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you're referring to [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/169512/disable-folder-auto-creation-in-onedrive-under-marshmallow)? If your bounty still has, say, 3 days left before it expires, then your bounty hasn't officially "failed" yet. There's still 3 days (well, at this point, 15 hours on that question) left for somebody to post an an answer and receive the bounty.

*Your* issue seems to be that you disagree with the system regarding whether your bounty "failed" or not. You've already decided that it failed, but the system gives it 7 days before deciding. There would be no way for the system to know that any particular user has decided to lose hope after 4 days rather than 7 and thus stop notifications to that user.

So the solution is to either increase your personal definition of "my bounty failed" to 7 days, or learn to live with the notifications. I suppose you could also campaign to globally shorten the bounty expiration time, if you've got a compelling argument for it.

As for the messages you are receiving, one useful thing you can get out of them is [as Pandya mentions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292573/disable-bounty-related-notifications-if-there-is-no-answer-to-award-bounty/292574#comment950474_292573): Motivation. For example, if your question hasn't attracted any answers despite a bounty, perhaps it could be improved, etc. The rationale is that since you were willing to sacrifice points to a bounty, it's probably important enough to you to notify you that it's going to expire and get you motivated to figure out why it still hasn't received any answers and what you can do to change that. Of course, it's possible that you've got a great question, but simply nobody who read it has known the answer (yet).