# Don't suggest awarding a bounty if there are no answers

Tags: feature-request, bounties

If a bounty has ended for a question that doesn't have any answers, don't suggest awarding the bounty, some other text should be used.

When the reason for the bounty was *"This question has not received enough attention*" it's rubbing salt on the wound, otherwise it's just useless.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Per the bounty FAQ [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work), it's intentional that questions in the bounty grace period that get no answers, still get grace periods.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog how is this a duplicate? I understand how the system works, the link you sent explains how to award a bounty and what happens if there are no answers. I just think that the text saying I can award a bounty when I can't should be changed.

Comment: Note that here on Meta Stack Exchange, we close questions as duplicates of questions tagged [tag:faq] if the answer to that question also answers this question. See [this section of our FAQ on how Meta Stack Exchange works](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/47635/377214) and the last section of [our FAQ on duplicate closures](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10844/377214). Also, you tagged this as a bug, and the way your question is worded very strongly implies that there shouldn't be a grace period if there are no answers, for which the answer in the FAQ is that it's intended behavior.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog, I didn't mean to imply that the grace period should be removed, I think this is a UX bug and as such isn't answered by the faq answer.

Comment: My suggestion is to make it clear that the *wording* should be changed, because as I said, the way I read it, it seemed to me like you were asking to eliminate the grace period. Also, per our tag guidelines, such a question should have the [tag:feature-request] tag, not [tag:bug]. Make these changes and I'll retract my dupe vote.

Comment: @SonictheIntrovertedHedgehog changed to [tag:feature-request] (although the dev in me sees this a defect in an existing feature and not a feature-request.)

Comment: Retracted my dupe vote.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292573, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137987, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108370, https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186023